# How to update session value on the same page

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to make something related to paging, where i have a array of around 400-500  values..
i want to show 9 values at a time and then after clicking on NEXT button i want to show next 9 more..

Here is the part of the code i am using to call JS function onclick of button and that function's job is to get the count from the browser and set it to next value.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['count']=9;

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
function changelistnext()
{ ";
    $c=$_SESSION['count'];
    $c=$c+1;
    $e=$c+9;
    $_SESSION['count']=$e;    
echo "
alert($c)
alert($e)
}
</script>";
 ?>  
<button id='next' value='next' onclick='changelistnext()'>Next</button>
```

But everytime i click on the next it shows the same value....

Comment: It won't work in this way as you are tying to change the value of php variable using javascript which is not possible actually. Better you use AJAX to change the value of $c and $e and user them in your javascript function. If you need any help with AJAX, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't mix JavaScript and PHP** as if they were one and the same.

JavaScript is a **client-side language**, which is executed in your browser.

On the other hand, PHP is a **server script**, and *sessions* are also kept on server.

---

If you open your page's source code in a browser, you will see that the session stuff is not there - it was executed by PHP when the page was generated. You can't use sessions directly in JS.

The page contains essentially this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changelistnext()
{
    alert(some number) // value of C when the page was generated on server
    alert(some number) // ditto for E
}
</script>
```

You could use Ajax call to ask some script on your server to give you data for the next "page" - PHP script can access the Session variables and send what you want back to the browser.